# Angular Service Worker - dataGroups not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5, angular-service-worker

I'm trying to use Angular Service Worker, everything works fine except the `dataGroups` not working for me.

That's what I have in my `ngsw-config.json`:

```js
{
  ...
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/shipments/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In my network tab I see that the service worker always make the server call then falls back to the cache. see attached image.

[dataGroups - Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbcVF.jpg)

Notice the API I'm calling are on a different server, localhost vs some-server:8000,
I tried different using different URLs:
`"/shipments/**"`
`"/shipments"`
`"http:some-server:8000/shipments/**"` etc. but none worked.

My Environment:

- @angular 5.1.1
- Service-Worker 5.1.2
- Angular-Cli 1.6.0

Comment: probably it was because you didn't use https? 
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution to this, my api and ui were not on the same server, after changing them on the same one, and updating the config to the code bellow, and using HTTPS on my site, everything worked perfectly:

```
"dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/shipments"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Hello @Nadhir, do you know if it works by keeping API to an other IP if it's on HTTPS ?

Comment: Hi @Gilsdav  I think you can do that. check this example by Stephen Fluin an angular team https://github.com/StephenFluin/fluin.io/blob/master/src/ngsw-config.json

Comment: @nadir link is not availbale

Comment: @NadhirFalta i want yo cache api response when api is on different server

Comment: @AnkitRaonka By the time you may have found the solution, but for others who may end up here, you just need to add Urls as Absolute Urls

Comment: After much experimenting, I found the following handled my API on a different servers  "https://**/myAPI.php"   (Although in the end I decided it would be best just to hardcode them individually).