# How to cache data using the new Angular 5 service worker

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-service-worker

I tried to cache data from both REST API or websocket using the new Angular 5 service worker.
my ngsw-config.json contains:

`"dataGroups": [{
    "name": "api-freshness",
    "urls": [
      "https://firestore.googleapis.com/"
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "maxSize": 100,
      "maxAge": "1h",
      "timeout": "10s",
      "strategy": "freshness"
    }
  }]`

I also tried both sources and didn't manage to cache the data, when I turn off the wifi, the data is not available:

- https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/hnpwa-angular-5-progressive-web-app-service-worker-tutorial/
- https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/a-new-angular-service-worker-creating-automatic-progressive-web-apps-part-2-practice-3221471269a1

The assets are rendering fine.

I am using:

- chrome 63 on Ubuntu 14.0.4
- @angular/cli: 1.6.4
- Angular: 5.2.1

This is My network calls:
[image]

I am running on localhost,
In this particular app I'm trying to connect to firebase , but when trying to connect to local rails server it didn't succeeded as well.

**Do I miss something here?**

Comment: Can I see your network calls? can you take a screenshot of your network tab?? also, does the api and ui run on the same server ??

Comment: @NadhirFalta thanks for responding, I saw that you have another question on this topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144407/angular-service-worker-datagroups-not-working ) and maybe you managed to make it work. I added what you asked for.

Comment: do you get those rails server error when you run dev ?? not prod ? Also, on your network tab, can you click on the icon on the right of "View" and take  snapshot?

Comment: Can you post the whole ngsw-config file?

Comment: I maybe not direct to your question but with firestore you can use offline enable for caching everything for use when offline.

Comment: @giraffe_head were you able to get it running ?

Comment: @NadhirFalta I didn't worked it out, can you share a repo with working solution? I tried to use it both with rails and firebase, and in both cases it didn't work

Comment: @giraffe_head check this repo by Stephen Fluin an Angular Team member: https://github.com/StephenFluin/fluin.io/blob/master/src/ngsw-config.json

Comment: @NadhirFalta thanks, I think that I understood the issue, my calls are with XHR instead of fetch API, I implement it with fetch and give it another shot